# Weird formatting "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INFO error" on org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.export.prometheus.PrometheusScrapeEndpoint

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

I've started to notice recently a weird formatting error reported at the Prometheus integration level. The error stack is available below.

Any idea what could cause it?

Thanks!

I'm on springboot 2.5.2

> 2021-07-15T11:53:30.530Z <>
> {session=,trace=,span=,user=,client=,thread=http-nio-9099-exec-9}
> ERROR:
> [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat-1].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet]]
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat-1].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet]rlf(Servlet.service()
> for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw
> exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INFO] with root causeask)
> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INFO
> at io.prometheus.client.exporter.common.TextFormat.write004(TextFormat.java:72)
> ~[simpleclient_common-0.10.0.jar!/:?]
> at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.export.prometheus.TextOutputFormat$2.write(TextOutputFormat.java:57)
> ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.export.prometheus.PrometheusScrapeEndpoint.scrape(PrometheusScrapeEndpoint.java:58)
> ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
> at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor53.invoke(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:?]
> at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[?:?]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[?:?]
> at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282)
> ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
> at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:74)
> ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:60)
> ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$ServletWebOperationAdapter.handle(AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java:291)
> ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java:376)
> ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
> at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor52.invoke(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:?]
> at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[?:?]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[?:?]
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
> at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.servlet.CompositeHandlerAdapter.handle(CompositeHandlerAdapter.java:58)
> ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:764)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
> [?:?]
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
> [?:?]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]
> 2021-07-15T11:53:45.162Z <> {session=,trace=,span=,user=,client=,thread=http-nio-9099-exec-8}
> ERROR:
> [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat-1].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet]]
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat-1].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet]rlf(Servlet.service()
> for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw
> exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INFO] with root causeask)
> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INFO
> at io.prometheus.client.exporter.common.TextFormat.write004(TextFormat.java:72)
> ~[simpleclient_common-0.10.0.jar!/:?]
> at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.export.prometheus.TextOutputFormat$2.write(TextOutputFormat.java:57)
> ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.export.prometheus.PrometheusScrapeEndpoint.scrape(PrometheusScrapeEndpoint.java:58)
> ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
> at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor53.invoke(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:?]
> at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[?:?]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[?:?]
> at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282)
> ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
> at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:74)
> ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:60)
> ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$ServletWebOperationAdapter.handle(AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java:291)
> ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java:376)
> ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
> at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor52.invoke(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:?]
> at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[?:?]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[?:?]
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
> at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.servlet.CompositeHandlerAdapter.handle(CompositeHandlerAdapter.java:58)
> ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.5.2.jar!/:2.5.2]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:764)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
> [?:?]
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
> [?:?]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar!/:?]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exception indicates that the problem occurred at [line 72 of TextFormat](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java/blob/eb4e694b00024043f948e407510f516dea58cbc7/simpleclient_common/src/main/java/io/prometheus/client/exporter/common/TextFormat.java#L72) where it refers to `Collector.Type.INFO`. `INFO` was [added](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java/commit/819a8576ccb159d4c3769ac49e97a59ae67858fc) in version 0.10.0 of Prometheus's Java client.

I can tell from the stack trace that you're using 0.10.0 of `simpleclient_common`. It's this jar that contains `TextFormat`. `Collector.Type` is part of the client's `simpleclient` module. You must be using an earlier version of this module so the `INFO` value is missing from the `Collector.Type` enum.

You need to update your `build.gradle` or `pom.xml` file to correct the versions of your dependencies to ensure that each of the Prometheus Client's modules that you're using has the same version.

Comment: Thanks! I had an older version of simpleclient  loaded by another library. Forcing the latest version across my project, solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks. So I need to make sure the version of simpleclient_common(introduced by micrometer-core) and simpleclient(introduced by io.prometheus.jmx:collector) are the same/as close as possible. At last I go with micrometer 1.8.3(simple_common 0.12.0) and jmx collector 0.16.1(simpleclient 0.11.0). Not the same, but this error disappears.